# Star Trek: Alien Domain weapon

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, video-games

In the new game [Star Trek: Alien Domain](http://startrek.gamesamba.com/) I have noticed a weapon on the Voyager that was never used in the TV series called the

> "Pulse nova attack"

I can find no reference to this weapon outside of this game. **If this was a genuine weapon then how come we never got to see it in the series? Did the game introduce this new weapon?**

Comment: In the game Star Trek: Elite Forces we see the introduction of the 'infinity modulator' which allowed it to overcome the Borg's adaptability to energy weapons. This was an in-game weapon only, and never appeared on Voyager (though the game took place there).

Answer (score 2):

The 'Pulse Nova' appears to be an entirely new invention for this game. Certainly no weapon that looks or acts like this (basically a blue space-lightning bolt that destroys things) appears in any episode of the Voyager TV shows, nor is there any mention of such a thing in any of the episode scripts.

---

As to how the creators of this game managed to come up with this innovative weapon, having looked over the [list of weapons + technology](http://www.alien-domain.ru/ad-glossary/) available in the game, the general impression seems to be that the writers simply took a list of Star Trek treknobabble and jumbled it up with different kinds of tech found elsewhere in the canon.

Examples of this "*mix'n'match*" include Tetryon Cannons, Quantum Shields, Polaron Turrets, Plasma Beams, Ethereal Shields, Disruptor Rays and Antiproton Turrets, none of which appear in any Star Trek property.

Comment: [Photonic cannon](https://youtu.be/LQo0fBzMO8Y?t=1m57s). Overcompensating, Doctor?